# Is there an alternative way of starting "The Raid" quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Wujeeta doesn't want to say anything cause she fears they might kill her.
All my options aren't very nice to her (persuade, bribe or intimidate).
So I tried to pickpocket her, and to my surprise, she does have a purchase agreement that reveals whos the dealer...
But the quest doesn't advance by reading it. What's even the point of that item existence?
I imagine either there's a way or the developers abandoned it half the way (as is the case for many quests dangling content)

Comment: 'All my options arent very nice to her (persuade, bribe or intimidate). So I tried to pickpocket her,' Uhm, what? Pickpocketing is nicer than persuading?

Comment: what the eyes dont see, the heart doesnt feel